# Two field separators (colon and space) in awk

Tags: awk

How can we specify two field separators in awk command when one of them is space? I think this can be done by using an embedded if-else condition in awk, however I am not sure about the exact command.

Sample file is as below:

```
cat test.txt
Swapnil Engineer 20000
Avinash:Doctor:30000
Dattu GovntJob 50000
Amol:Master:10000
```

I want to print the second column ($2). Expected output is:

```
Engineer
Doctor
GovntJob
Master
```

When I tried to put both space and colon as field seperators, it failed with a syntax error:

```
awk -F[ :] '{print $2}' test.txt
awk: cmd. line:1: :]
awk: cmd. line:1: ^ syntax error
```

How can we use two field separators and utilize awk functionality?

Comment: In addition to Yeti's answer, remember that the shell splits by unquoted whitespace to create the list of arguments to awk, so instead of `-F[ :]` (one arg) it got `-F[:` and `]`. [This chart](http://kamelzcs.github.io/images/posts/bash-commandline/bash.jpg) is quite handy (note the vertical arrows for single/double quotes).

Comment: Thanks ArielCo, much appreciated!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are on the right track!
Just add the missing quotes around `[ :]`:

```
awk -F'[ :]' '{print $2}' test.txt
Engineer
Doctor
GovntJob
Master
```